# Gröbner implicitization with relationships between the variables

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computer-algebra, mathematical-software, groebner-bases

I have the following parametric equations, where `cost`$=\cos t$, `cos2t`$=\cos 2t$, and $A^2+B^2=1$:

```
x = A*cost*cos2t - sint*sin2t, y = A*sint*cos2t + cost*sin2t, z = B*cos2t
```

I want to transform this system into an implicit equation with the help of Gröbner bases. In the Sage software, I do:

```
R.<x, y, z, A, B, cost, sint, cos2t, sin2t> = PolynomialRing(QQ, 9)
I = R.ideal([x - A*cost*cos2t + sint*sin2t, y - A*sint*cos2t - cost*sin2t, z - B*cos2t, A^2 + B^2 - 1, cost^2 + sint^2 - 1, cos2t - cost^2 + sint^2, sin2t - 2*sint*cost])
I.elimination_ideal([cost, sint, cos2t, sin2t])
```

Sage fastly returns three polynomials (including `A^2+B^2-1`).

Now I want to do it with Xcas/Giac (Xcas is the graphical interface to Giac). The Gröbner implicitization is not implemented, only Gröbner bases. So I request the Gröbner basis for:

```
x - A*cost*cos2t + sint*sin2t, 
y - A*sint*cos2t - cost*sin2t, 
z - B*cos2t, 
A^2 + B^2 - 1, 
cost^2 + sint^2 - 1, 
cos2t - cost^2 + sint^2, 
sin2t - 2*sint*cost
```

with the variables (the order is important) `cost, sint, cos2t, sin2t, A, B, x, y, z`.

This crashes my computer because of memory allocation. But if I manually plug the equalities `cos2t = cost^2 - sint^2, sin2t = 2*sint*cost` in the first three polynomials, and then I remove the two variables `cos2t` and `sin2t`, the laptop does not crash, and Giac returns a Gröbner basis having among its elements *seven* polynomials not involving `cost` and `sint`.

So I'm wondering how Sage works. I have Cox & al's book but they don't explain how to proceed when there are relations among the variables (such as `cos2t = cost^2 - sint^2, sin2t = 2*sint*cost`) and constant parameters (`A` and `B`). What is the Gröbner basis I should request in order to get the same result as Sage, with which order among the variables?

---

## Edit

My laptop does not crash anymore. The crash was due to a bad choice of the monomial order. And I have been able to get the right answer. But for the similar example with $\cos 3t$ and $\sin 3t$, I don't get the right answer. However I get it if I replace $A$ and $B$ by numerical values. This also works better when I plug the expanded expressions $\cos 3t$ and $\sin 3t$ in the equations. Sage has an option to use Giac, so there should be a solution.

Please say me if my question is not clear and I'll try to improve it.

Comment: I see that someone voted to close. So my question should not be clear enough, because this is a purely mathematical question of algebraic geometry.

Comment: Cross-posted to Ask SageMath: [How to reproduce `elimination_ideal` with Giac ?](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/70816/how-to-reproduce-elimination_ideal-with-giac/)

Comment: @RicardoBuring Yes, and I talked to a Giac developer. He told me Giac uses a "double order" to perform elimination. I'd like to know more about that, from the theoretical point of view, not for a software purpose.

Comment: Here is the Giac source for `eliminate`: https://github.com/geogebra/giac/blob/c71a9055f4848d107bb8d5bf23e7523814777fd5/src/giac/cpp/solve.cc#L7854-L8222